# Android Function Equivilent

Tags: android, function, object

I'm trying to create something similar to a function in Android but I don't know where to start. I'll then put those objects in a vector. If you haven't noticed, I'm coming from c++. I've done some looking around but I am currently in China, and the Great Firewall does not like the google developer website :(

```
package example.package.com

import android.stuff
import more.android.stuff

public class main extends Activity {

    obj myObj = new obj();

    myObj.doSomething;

    Vector<obj> vObjs = new Vector<obj>();

    vObjs.add(myObj);
}

class obj {

    int variable;
    String word;

    public int getVariable() {

        return variable;
    }

    public void doSomething() {

        this.variable++
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not even valid Java syntax...

Comment: @Raptor - of course it isn't.  The poster is trying to figure out how to express a general computing concept in Java syntax - if it were already in Java, there wouldn't be a question here.

Comment: The API for Guava's [`Function`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) may give you some hints, if you can access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can do any of this you MUST familiarize yourself with Android and its Activity lifecycle so you can appropriately create everything you need.

You need java to understand the syntax and Android API (dev docs) and if you can't use the dev site, i'm sure you can find multiple examples of creating a simple Activity in android. In fact, you could just create a test app and you would have the majority of what you'd need to get your Activity working.

Case and point:

The google dev site is not your only source of information.

Comment: I've tinkered with Android quite a bit, but instead of ever using something like a function, I just worked around it. However, this really limited the apps functionality (no pun intended). Instead of being able to create these objects and store them in an array/vector, I had to hard code each objects variable into the program that puts a limit on how many objects can be created. I've also never downloaded additional libraries. I'll take a look a Guava and see what I can come up with. Functions are such a simple concept, you'd think there would be something similar to them in java.

Comment: submitted an answer after I found what I needed. Since this set me on the right path, I'll accept this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Guava library has Functions and Predicates.
See https://github.com/google/guava

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I was asking the wrong question. I was almost there. I found an example of what I needed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

So, I create a class, fill it with variables, a constructor, and a bunch of methods. Create an object based on that class and then create a vector of objects for the class to fit into. Easy, I just needed to know what I was looking for. Thanks everyone, you all pointed me in the right direction!